# Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, exception, vector

i have a little problem with my game. When i'm trying to check that the bullet and ennemy are colliding i'm randomly getting an error "Vector subscript out of range", im not sure that this is a problem, but i'm deleting my vector in two places:

```
//Checking if enemy is crossing a bullet
        for (size_t i = 0; i < ennemies.size(); i++)
        {
            ennemies[i].update(player);

            if (player.getGlobalBounds().intersects(ennemies[i].getGlobalBounds()))
            {
                player.kill();
            }

            for (size_t j = 0; j < bullets.size(); j++)
            {
                if (ennemies[i].getGlobalBounds().intersects(bullets[j].getGlobalBounds()))
                {
                    ennemies.erase(ennemies.begin() + i);
                    bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + j);
                    ilosc--;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the second place:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Level::LEVEL_HEIGHT; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Level::LEVEL_WIDTH; j++)
    {
        if (level.tiles[i][j].tileType != 0)
        {
            if (x.intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                kolX = true;
            else if (y.intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                kolY = true;

            for (int k = 0; k < bullets.size(); k++)
            {
                if (bullets[k].getGlobalBounds().intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                {
                    bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + k);
                    ilosc--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the whole code of a main class:

```
    #include "Engine.h"

Engine::Engine()
{
    //wczytywanie bg
    bgTexture.loadFromFile("data\\textures\\bg.png");
    bgSprite.setTexture(bgTexture);

    //wczytywanie textur
    for (int i = 1; i < level.iloscTextur; i++)
    {
        tiles[i].loadFromFile("data\\textures\\tiles.png", IntRect((i-1)*level.TILE_WIDTH, 0, 32, 32));
    }

    //ustawianie kafli
    for (int i = 0; i < Level::LEVEL_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Level::LEVEL_WIDTH; j++)
        {
            if (level.tiles[i][j].tileType != 0)
            {
                map[i][j].setPosition(j * Level::TILE_WIDTH, i * Level::TILE_HEIGHT);
                map[i][j].setTexture(tiles[level.tiles[i][j].tileType]);
            }
        }
    }
}

Engine::~Engine()
{

}

//Renderowany poziom gry

void Engine::runEngine(RenderWindow & window)
{
    //Zegary do pętli stałokrokowej, pocisków i przeciwników
    Time UpdateTime = Time::Zero;
    Time czasOdPocisku = Time::Zero;
    Time czasDoSpawnu = Time::Zero;

    Clock przeciwnicy;
    Clock zegar;
    Clock czasPocisku;

    const Time StepTime = seconds(1.f / 60.f);
    const Time WaitTime = seconds(0.1);
    Time EnemySpawn = enemy.losujSpawn();

    bool menu = false;

    while (!menu)
    {
        Time czas = zegar.restart();
        UpdateTime += czas;

        //Pętla aktualizujaca logikę gry

        while (UpdateTime > StepTime)
        {
            czasOdPocisku = czasPocisku.getElapsedTime();
            czasDoSpawnu = przeciwnicy.getElapsedTime();

            UpdateTime -= StepTime;
            Event event;
            Vector2f mouse = window.mapPixelToCoords(Mouse::getPosition(window));   

            player.update(mouse);

            if (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                    menu = true;

                if ((Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left) && WaitTime < czasOdPocisku) || (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right) && WaitTime < czasOdPocisku) ||
                    (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up) && WaitTime < czasOdPocisku) || (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down) && WaitTime < czasOdPocisku))
                {
                    czasPocisku.restart();

                    bullets.push_back(bullet);
                    bullets[ilosc].addBullet(player);
                    ilosc++;
                }
            }

            //Spawn przeciwników


            if (EnemySpawn < czasDoSpawnu)
            {
                czasDoSpawnu = przeciwnicy.restart();
                EnemySpawn = enemy.losujSpawn();
                for (int i = 0; i < enemy.losujPrzeciwnikow(); i++)
                    ennemies.push_back(enemy);
            }

            //aktualizacje logiki

            for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
            {
                bullets[i].update();
            }

            //Checking if enemy is crossing a bullet
            for (size_t i = 0; i < ennemies.size(); i++)
            {
                ennemies[i].update(player);

                if (player.getGlobalBounds().intersects(ennemies[i].getGlobalBounds()))
                {
                    player.kill();
                }

                for (size_t j = 0; j < bullets.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (ennemies[i].getGlobalBounds().intersects(bullets[j].getGlobalBounds()))
                    {
                        ennemies.erase(ennemies.begin() + i);
                        bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + j);
                        ilosc--;
                    }
                }
            }
            czyKoliduje(player.ruch(StepTime));
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(bgSprite);

        //Rysowanie poziomu

        for (int i = 0; i < Level::LEVEL_HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Level::LEVEL_WIDTH; j++)
            {
                window.draw(map[i][j]);
            }
        }

        //Rysowanie pociskow

        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
        {
            window.draw(bullets[i]);
        }   

        for (int i = 0; i < ennemies.size(); i++)
        {
            window.draw(ennemies[i]);
        }

        window.draw(player);
        window.display();
    }
}

//Kolizje

void Engine::czyKoliduje(Vector2f ruch)
{

    FloatRect x = player.getGlobalBounds();
    FloatRect y = player.getGlobalBounds();

    x.left += ruch.x;
    y.top += ruch.y;

    bool kolY = false, kolX = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < Level::LEVEL_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Level::LEVEL_WIDTH; j++)
        {
            if (level.tiles[i][j].tileType != 0)
            {
                if (x.intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                    kolX = true;
                else if (y.intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                    kolY = true;

                for (int k = 0; k < bullets.size(); k++)
                {
                    if (bullets[k].getGlobalBounds().intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                    {
                        bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + k);
                        ilosc--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!kolX)
        player.move(Vector2f(ruch.x, 0));
    if (!kolY)
        player.move(Vector2f(0, ruch.y));
}
```

Comment: Assuming for the moment the implied, unasked question here is "Why am I getting a subscript-out-of-range error, this is what a *debugger* is made for. Until such time as you have solid coverage of unit tests that breed high-confidence your subscripts will always be in-range, I suggest you 1. use `.at()` instead of the subscripting `operator[]` for your vectors, and 2. *use a debugger*.

Comment: You're erasing `ennemies[i]` but leaving the value of `i` unchanged. If the last enemy in the list is erased, next loop iteration you'll be beyond the bounds of the vector. Also, "enemies" only has one 'n'.

Comment: @JonathanPotter same with `bullets`. If you want to remove items from a container while looping through it, you need to use iterators instead of indexes. `erase()` returns a new iterator that points to the item after the erased item, so you can continue looping.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think `bullets` is ok (in terms of out-of-bounds access) because the loop evaluates the vector size each time through. Of course results may be inconsistent.

Comment: @JonathanPotter the loops through `bullets` are also affected by index mis-management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your loops that are calling `erase()` on containers are not taking into account that the size of the containers change when you erase items from them. To *properly* loop through a container *while* erasing items from it, you should use iterators instead of indexes. `erase()` returns a new iterator that points to the item after the erased item, so you can continue looping.

```
std::vector<enemy>::iterator i = ennemies.begin();
while (i != ennemies.end())
{
    i->update(player);

    if (player.getGlobalBounds().intersects(i->getGlobalBounds()))
    {
        player.kill();
    }

    bool hit = false;
    for (std::vector<bullet>::iterator j = bullets.begin(); j != bullets.end); ++j)
    {
        if (i->getGlobalBounds().intersects(j->getGlobalBounds()))
        {
            hit = true;
            i = ennemies.erase(i);
            j = bullets.erase(j);
            ilosc--;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!hit)
        ++i;
}
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < Level::LEVEL_HEIGHT; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Level::LEVEL_WIDTH; j++)
    {
        if (level.tiles[i][j].tileType != 0)
        {
            if (x.intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                kolX = true;
            else if (y.intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                kolY = true;

            std::vector<bullet>::iterator k = bullets.begin();
            while (k != bullets.end())
            {
                if (k->getGlobalBounds().intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                {
                    k = bullets.erase(k);
                    ilosc--;
                }
                else
                    ++k;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that said, you might consider using [`std::remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead of manual `erase()` loops:

```
template<typename SourceType, typename TargetType>
struct intersectsBounds
{
    TargetType &m_target;

    intersectsBounds(TargetType &target) : m_target(target) {}

    bool operator()(const SourceType &source) const
    {
        return source.getGlobalBounds().intersects(m_target.getGlobalBounds());
    }
};
```

```
std::vector<enemy>::iterator i = ennemies.begin();
while (i != ennemies.end())
{
    i->update(player);

    if (player.getGlobalBounds().intersects(i->getGlobalBounds()))
    {
        player.kill();
    }

    std::vector<bullet>::iterator j = std::remove_if(bullets.begin(), bullets.end(), intersectsBounds(*i));
    if (j != bullets.end())
    {
        i = ennemies.erase(i);

        int numErased = std::distance(j, bullets.end());
        bullets.erase(j, bullets.end());
        ilosc -= numErased;
    }
    else
        ++i;
}
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < Level::LEVEL_HEIGHT; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Level::LEVEL_WIDTH; j++)
    {
        if (level.tiles[i][j].tileType != 0)
        {
            if (x.intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                kolX = true;
            else if (y.intersects(map[i][j].getGlobalBounds()))
                kolY = true;

            std::vector<bullet>::iterator k = std::remove_if(bullets.begin(), bullets.end(), intersectsBounds(map[i][j]));
            if (k != bullets.end())
            {
                int numErased = std::distance(k, bullets.end());
                bullets.erase(k, bullets.end());
                ilosc -= numErased;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for help. :) You realy helped me with my issue. I have never thought that i can fix it like this, especially that i didn't know smth. like "iterator " before. I think that the 1st sollution is much simppler . Anyway once again thanks for the effort.